# Scala method syntax problem

Tags: scala

I am learning scala, and meet a little problem. I want to use the String method stripMargin as following. But I can not add parenthesis on this method. I remember that no-argument method's parenthesis is optional, so here why I can not add parenthesis ?

```
val str=""" hello world
    |" ANd soe"
    |" to world"""

println(str.stripMargin())  // won't compile
println(str.stripMargin)  // compiles successfully
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the method without parameters in define with `()`, then writing `()` is optional. If the method is defined without `()`, then adding `()` is not allowed (or, rather, is interpreted as if you were calling `apply()` on the returned result).

Good practice recommends that a method without side effects be defined without `()`, and to keep `()` both at definition site and call site when it has side effects.